# Uncertainty Principle - measuring momentum on one entangled particle, position on the other

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

If two entangled particles are sent far apart and then at exactly the same time the position of one, and the momentum of the other, is measured, won't this mean that, because the corresponding values for the other particle will be known, that both momentum and position will be known precisely?